# Wingpanel remains black after clicking on the Desktop icon

Tags: wingpanel

Usually the Wingpanel goes transparent when there is no window maximized. But when I have a windows maximized and then click on the Desktop icon (placed from the Docklets by `Ctrl + right click` on the dock), it shows the desktop but the wingpanel remains black. Not important but just thought I'd report. Thank you.

Comment: This is not the place for bug reports. Github is. https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/issues check if your issues has already been reported, before creating a new one.

Comment: Thank you very much. And sorry for the mistake.

Comment: A small sidenote. If you're using custom themes, that might be the reason. Themes are technically not supported.